# Cannot find "display options" in profile settings

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface

Are there some options for tweaking how SE pages are displayed in browser? E.g. many forums offer options for turning off certain kind of graphic details: images in posts, avatars, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there some options for tweaking how SE pages are displayed in browser?

No, there aren't.

You can always use a [user stylesheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm) or a userscript to customize the site to your liking.